# How to Increase number of cpus on Docker

Tags: docker, cpu

When I run Docker Info on my machine, I get this:

```
Containers: 0
Images: 21
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 21
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.1.13-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.9.1 (TCL 6.4.1); master : cef800b - Fri             Nov 20 19:33:59 UTC 2015
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 996.2 MiB
Name: default
```

I have a MAC Pro with 8 cpus. But it is showing only one cpu here. How do I increase the number of cpus on Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Boot2Docker" is a virtual machine running under VirtualBox at your Mac. So you should increase the number of CPUs available to the VM in VirtualBox interface.